# Cannot get access to properties on payload in the reducers when dispatching actions using react-redux and typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, redux, react-redux, dispatch

In my reducers I want to access the payload property to update the store, but Typescript seems to complain about the type of the property that I want to access.

//_constants.ts

```
export const resultsConstants = {
  STORE_RESULT: "STORE_RESULT",
  DELETE_RESULT: "DELETE_RESULT",
};
```

//_actiontypes.ts

```
import { resultsConstants } from "../../_constants";

export interface StoreResult {
  type: typeof resultsConstants.STORE_RESULT;
  payload: { value: number };
}

export interface DeleteResult {
  type: typeof resultsConstants.DELETE_RESULT;
  payload: {
    id: string;
  };
}
```

// results.actions.ts dispatching

```
export const storeResult = (val: number) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<StoreResult>) => {
    dispatch({
      type: resultsConstants.STORE_RESULT,
      payload: { value: val },
    });
  };
};

export const deleteResult = (id: string) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<DeleteResult>) => {
    dispatch({ type: resultsConstants.DELETE_RESULT, payload: { id: id } });
  };
};

export type ResultActionTypes = StoreResult | DeleteResult;
```

// reducer.ts

```
const initialState: StoredResults = {
  results: [],
};

export const results = (
  state = initialState,
  action: ResultActionTypes
): StoredResults => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case resultsConstants.DELETE_RESULT:
      return state;
    case resultsConstants.STORE_RESULT:
      const oldState = { ...state };
      oldState.results = state.results.concat(action.payload.value); /* cannot access this value here */
      return { ...state };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is the error I am getting from TS:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type '{ value: number; } | { id: string; }'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type '{ id: string; }'.ts(2339)
```

Even though I combined the actiontypes in the results.actions.ts files it complains that the `value` property does not exist on the action type that is passed by the dispatching function.

Any help or advice on how to do it differently would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

By further splitting the action type interfaces into a payload interface, and typecasting the payload in the reducer, I got this to work:

// results.types.ts

```
export interface StoreResultPayload {
  value: number;
}

export interface StoreResultType {
  type: typeof resultsConstants.STORE_RESULT;
  payload: StoreResultPayload;
}
```

// results.reducer.ts

```
const val = action.payload as StoreResultPayload;
oldState.results = state.results.concat(val.value);
```

This still feels like a workaround for me. Shouldn't typescript be able to infer the payload anyway due to the action types being combined with the union operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecasting the payload object (to tell Typescript: "Trust me, I know what I am doing") is the only workaround I could find for now. See the edited version of the question for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works

```
interface StorePayload {
  value: number;
}

interface DeletePayload {
  value: string;
}

export interface StoreResult {
  type: string;
  payload: StorePayload
}

export interface DeleteResult {
  type: string;
  payload: DeletePayload;
}
```

Comment: Yes this could work with a bit more code in the reducer. Before accessing the properties on the `action` type I cast the `action.payload` to the specific Payload interface. Will edit the question with the changed lines. But this still seems like a workaround for me. Shouldn't Typescript be able to infer the properties on the action since the action type interfaces are combined using the union operator?

Comment: I think you have to explicitly define the property and type with interfaces.